# Splunk - How to get results only if search field contains a word in the lookup table

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

***If I have a search result which has a field named "Field1" and It has values like :***

This is Word1 now.

This is Word2 now.

This is WordX now.

This is WordZ now.

***Below is the lookup table for Words.***

**Field1**

Word1

Word2

Word3

Word4

Word5

Word6

***How can I search so I get ONLY below results in the output because they contain "Word1" and "Word2" which are in the lookup table?***

This is Word1 now.

This is Word2 now.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to read the lookup file in a subsearch.

```
index=foo [ | inputlookup words.csv | format ]
```

The `format` command puts the contents of the lookup file into field=value format so the final query becomes `index=foo ((field1=Word1) OR (field1=Word2))`.